# Get BitLocker recovery password

Tags: windows, powershell, bitlocker

I am using the following PowerShell code to encrypt a drive. When I run it's it gives the following output and I am not able to assign it to a variable. It does not seem like a regular output. Any help is appreciated.

Code:

```
Enable-BitLocker -MountPoint $MountPoint -EncryptionMethod Aes256 -UsedSpaceOnly -RecoveryPasswordProtector
```

Output:

```
    WARNING: ACTIONS REQUIRED:

1. Save this numerical recovery password in a secure location away from your computer:

405273-201047-403040-618189-117755-037620-586223-109186

To prevent data loss, save this password immediately. This password helps ensure that you can unlock the encrypted volume.
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After you have run that command to encrypt the drive, you can get the key via:

`(Get-BitLockerVolume -MountPoint D:).KeyProtector.RecoveryPassword`

You just need to replace the drive:  D: with the drive you encrypted. Note though this is only for this type of manual password recovery. In a domain environment its better to backup the key to Active Directory rather than keeping it just as txt file somewhere.

Comment: I also see that when I run Enable-BitLocker it sometimes lock the data drive. I have included the following line to autounlock right after enabling bitlocker but it doesn't  seem to be working. I see sometime the drives are getting locked. Do you know the reason and a way to overcome this? 
Enable-BitLocker -MountPoint $drive -EncryptionMethod Aes256 -UsedSpaceOnly -RecoveryPasswordProtector
Enable-BitLockerAutoUnlock -MountPoint $drive

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Does it error? or Doesnt error, but after a restart the drive is locked still or something like that?